# Android NDK: Could not find platform files (headers and libraries)

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build

Error message:

[image: Error message]

Actually,my environment is good when my disk not broken. However,when I change a new disk, download new ndk package, then set my NDK_ROOT, and ANDROID_NDK, like this:

Env variables:

[image: Env variables]

my ndk-build is not working. Is something wrong in my environment?

Comment: Hi. Have you done the advice given by the first message ?

Comment: You don't have to add NDK_ROOT to your %PATH%, but this may be nice. Note that your error message points to a different path on disk **D:**, maybe it's stuck on your %PATH% after reinstall.

Comment: Could be that you're using ndk-build from your C: drive but clobbering its definition of `NDK_ROOT` (this is an variable internal to ndk-build that your environment may be overriding) with the path to the one in D:. That's definitely something that the build system won't be able to cope with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for Android JNI: https://github.com/russell-shizhen/JniExample, you should start from some tutorial project first.